# How to fix incorrect next and previous days when dealing with daylight saving time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a calendar in my app which I populate through the native `Calendar` object.
I have extended the calendar to do the following:

```
extension Calendar {
    func nextMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
        return self.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date) ?? Date().localDate()
    }
    func previousMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
        return self.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date) ?? Date().localDate()
    }
    func nextDay(date: Date) -> Date {
        return self.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) ?? Date().localDate()
    }
    func previousDay(date: Date) -> Date {
        return self.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) ?? Date().localDate()
    }
}
```

I recently noticed a bug for the date of October 30. I am based in France but this bug has happened to people living in other countries as well.

If the user taps on Oct 31 and tries to see the previous day, which is Oct 30, this is what shows on my logs:

```
-> 2022-10-31 00:00:00 +0000
-> 2022-10-29 23:00:00 +0000
```

And if the user taps on Oct 30 and tries to see the next day, which is Oct 31, this is what shows on my logs:

```
-> 2022-10-30 00:00:00 +0000
-> 2022-10-31 01:00:00 +0000
```

Notice the issue in the first case. October 30 was skipped. As for the next one, I am getting a time although I want midnight dates.

The functions `nextDay` and `previousDay`  are called this way:

```
Calendar.current.nextDay(date: date)
Calendar.current.previousDay(date: date)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here, GMT has no daylight savings so 29th Oct at 23:00 is 30 Oct in your timezone. So if anything you have a problem with your DateFormatter

Comment: I just need it to output the actual previous and next days, at midnight. I don't want this to be the output ```2022-10-29 23:00:00 +0000```. I want it to be: ```2022-10-30 00:00:00 +0000```.